# Wait trigger data only catching the first event

Tags: events, system-verilog, uvm

I am using **OVM**

My code is triggering an ovm event in one place (I added a print to confirm). However, in another place I'm waiting for that trigger and it's only "caught" once (also here I added a print to confirm).

```
function void trigger_event_for_incoming_transaction(ovm_object txn);
    if (is_type_1(txn))
      type_1.trigger(txn);            
endfunction
```

And somewhere else:

```
    task look_for_type_1();    
      forever begin
        type_1.wait_trigger_data(my_obj);
      end
    endtask
```

I can't paste most of the code due to intelucatal property...
But I registered event properly etc.

Comment: you need to provide more information. it is absolutely unclear what your type_1 is and how it works with 'events'. How and where the variable is declared in both cases, ... Would be good if you can provide a small reproducible example. However, i am not sure if there is still a lot of ovm around. Why not use 'uvm'?

Comment: It's an old project...
What exactly do you need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OVM/UVM's trigger and wait_trigger works the same as SystemVerilog's event trigger `->e` and event control `@e`—the event control has to block waiting for the trigger *before* executing the trigger. You can use the triggered method of an event in `wait(e.triggered())` which returns true from the point when the triggered until the end of the time step. Then the ordering between the trigger and the event control within the time step no longer matters; a **p**ersistent **trigger**.

You can try using OVM's `wait_ptrigger_data` which uses this triggered method underneath.